# How to change the algorithm implication by changing the invariant?

Tags: algorithms, hoare-logic

I have this specification in GCL:

$[Ctx C: n\geqslant 0\ \wedge\ b:[0..n-1]\ \text{of int}$

$\{Q:\text{True}\}$

$sum,i:=0,0;$

$\{\text{Invariant}\ P: 0\leqslant i \leqslant n\ \wedge sum=\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} b[j]\}$

$\{T:n-i\}$

$do\ i\neq n \rightarrow\ sum, i:=sum+b[i],i+1;\ od$

$\{R: sum=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} b[j]\}$

$]$

But then I have been requested to develop the same summation of the numbers located in $b$ but with the following invariant and dimension function ($T$):

$\{\text{Invariant}\ P: 0\leqslant i \leqslant n\ \wedge sum=\sum_{j=i}^{n-1} 
b[j]\}$

and

$\{T:i\}$

But I don't how to proceed. What I firstly supposed is that the summation must be done in reverse order.

Some suggestion, ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the new invariant does not hold in the code you posted, so I guess you are asked to change the code accordingly.

> What I firstly supposed is that the summation must be done in reverse order.

That might be a wise choice. You could try something like this:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
sum,i:=0,n;
\\
\{\text{Invariant}\ P: 0\leqslant i \leqslant n\ \wedge sum=\sum_{j=i}^{n-1} b[j]\}
\\
\{T:i\}
\\
do\ i\neq 0 \rightarrow\ sum, i:=sum+b[i-1],i-1;\ od
\\
\{R: sum=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} b[j]\}
\end{array}
$$

I have not checked that this Hoare triple is valid, but it should be, possibly with some minor changes.

Comment: thanks. It is what I have supposed by simple inspection: the summation starts in the last index of the array and ends in the first position (0). So in this, can we say that the $T$ function 'ends' when $i$ reaches the $0$ value?

Comment: @InfZero Yes, that's what happens.

Answer (score 2):

We wish to establish

```
R : sum = ∑ j : 0..n-1 • b[j]
```

using invariant

```
P : 0 ≤ i ≤ n ∧ sum = ∑ j : i..n-1 • b[j]
```

Well we clearly have `P ⇒ R` if we know `i = 0`, so let's
use a loop with its negation as guard.

Now this loop will terminate if we reduce `i`, so let's place
`i ≔ i -1` in the loop body while also attempting to maintain
`P`; i.e., solve for `X` in `P ∧ i ≠ 0 ⇒ P [sum, i ≔ X , i - 1 ]`.

Indeed, let us assume `P` and `i ≠ 0` and solve for `X`:

```
  P [sum, i ≔ X , i - 1 ]
≡⟪ definition of P and substitution ⟫
  0 ≤ i - 1 ≤ n ∧ X = ∑ j : i-1..n-1 • b[j]
≡⟪ arithmetic ⟫
  1 ≤ i ≤ n + 1 ∧ X = ∑ j : i-1..n-1 • b[j]
≡⟪ Assumptions i ≠ 0 and P ensure 1 ≤ i ≤ n + 1 ⟫
  X = ∑ j : i-1..n-1 • b[j]
≡⟪ quantifiers: term split off rule ⟫
  X = b[i - 1] + ∑ j : i..n-1 • b[j]
≡⟪ assumption P yields sum = ∑ j : i..n-1 • b[j] ⟫
  X = b[i - 1] + sum
```

Hence, we have arrived at the appropriate loop-body
by *mere calculation*: `sum, i ≔ b[i - 1] + sum, i - 1`.

Of course our loop will not begin if our variables are not
initialized correctly, and indeed `P`, that is
`0 ≤ i ≤ n ∧ sum = ∑ j : i..n-1 • b[j]` is easily truthified
by setting `i ≔ 0`, since `0 ≤ n`, resulting in an empty sum and thus `sum ≔ 0`.

In summary, we have *calculated*

```
{ 0 ≤ n }
sum, i ≔ 0, n
{ Invaraint: 0 ≤ i ≤ n ∧ sum = ∑ j : i..n-1 • b[j]
  bound: i }
do i ≠ 0 → sum, i ≔ b[i - 1] + sum, i - 1 od
{ sum = ∑ j : 0..n-1 • b[j] }
```